# How to construct a grammar that generates language L?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

I'm in a Formal languages class and have a grammar quiz coming up. I'm assuming something like this will appear.

Consider the alphabet $\Sigma$ = {a, b, c}. Construct a grammar that generates the language $L = \{bab^nabc^na^p \mid n ≥ 0, p ≥ 1\}$. Assume that the start variable is $S$.

Comment: and the problem is...? if there is no restriction on the grammar, there are many possible solution; I assume you meant a context-free grammar.

Comment: What research have you done?  What have you tried?  Have you tried using the techniques in http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18524/755?  This question looks like it is answered by the answers there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible grammar is: $G = (N, \Sigma, P, S)$, 
where

$N = \{S,U,V\}$

$\Sigma = \{a,b,c\}$

$P = \{
  S \to baUV,
  U \to ab|bUc,
  V \to a|aV
\}$

The key observation here is breaking $bab^nabc^na^p$ into 3 parts, $ba$, $b^nabc^n$, and $a^p$, one fixed, one growing bidirectionally, and one simple repeatition. Express the growing patterns first, then merge them along with the fixed parts.